# cannot get the name value in multipleselect in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, select, native

```js
 items = [{
    id: '92iijs7yta',
    name: 'Ondo',
  }, {
    id: 'a0s0a8ssbsd',
    name: 'Ogun',
  }, {
    id: '16hbajsabsd',
    name: 'Calabar',
  }, {
    id: 'nahs75a5sg',
    name: 'Lagos',
  }, {
    id: '667atsas',
    name: 'Maiduguri',
  }, {
    id: 'hsyasajs',
    name: 'Anambra',
  }, {
    id: 'djsjudksjd',
    name: 'Benue',
  }, {
    id: 'sdhyaysdj',
    name: 'Kaduna',
  }, {
    id: 'suudydjsjd',
    name: 'Abuja',
  }];

onSelectedItemsChange = selectedItems => {
this.setState({ selectedItems });
alert({selectedItems});
}
    
render(){
const { selectedItems } = this.state;
return(
<React.Fragment>
<ScrollView>
<View style={styles.formView}>
    <MultiSelect
          hideTags
          items={this.items}
          uniqueKey="id"
          ref={(component) => { this.multiSelect = component }}
          onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
          selectedItems={selectedItems} 
          selectText="Select Company Services"
          searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Items..."
          tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
          tagBorderColor="#CCC"
          tagTextColor="#CCC"
          selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
          selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
          itemTextColor="#000"
          displayKey="name"
          searchInputStyle={{ color: '#CCC' }}
          submitButtonColor="#CCC"
          submitButtonText="Select"
        /> 
</View>
)}
```

this is my code inside onSelectedItemsChange function i need to retrive the name of the items but cannot, selectedItems only return id of the items array....

Comment: Does `MultiSelect` belong to this library? https://github.com/toystars/react-native-multiple-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in your onSelectedItemsChange to get the name of the Key that you are selected:

```
onSelectedItemsChange = selectedItems => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
    this.state.items.find(x => {
        if(x.id == selectedItems){
            console.log("x is ",x.name);
        }
    })
  };
```

Here in x.name you will be getting the name you had selected.

Hope this helps!